# How to Store Arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, database, kotlin

Hello stackoverflow family,

I Want to store `ArrayList` Data.

There are many ways to save it, but I want to know which is best storage option we have.

can you please Give me idea about which database is you prefer and why.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: This is opinion-based. There is no single answer to this, given the little requirements you provide.

Comment: can you please elaborate what is exact requirement?

Comment: Yes I just wants developer opinion.

Comment: If your list is very large and require some operations then use Room db. If list is small you can use sharedPreference or DataStore